# C# Console Application Screen Capture a rectangle around the mouse

Tags: c#, console-application, screen-capture

I am trying to screen capture a rectangle based on the X,Y position of the mouse.  I have a couple of issues with my code:

1.)I want the mouse cursor to be at the center of the rectangle(I don't need the cursor in the screen shot).
2.)The screenshots look ok on the first monitor but on the second monitor the screen shots seem to be offset.  The reason it is offset is because monitor #2 has Scale And Layout setting of 125%.

Any help with this would be appreciated thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Test
{
    public static class MouseScreenCapture
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT pt);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINT
        {
            public int X;
            public int Y;

            public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Point(POINT point)
            {
                return new System.Drawing.Point(point.X, point.Y);
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Start();
        }


        private static System.Threading.Timer _timer = null;
        public static void Start()
        {

            _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 5000);

        }


        private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
        {
            GetMousePositionAndScreenCapture();
        }


        public static void GetMousePositionAndScreenCapture()
        {

            POINT lpPoint ;
            GetCursorPos(out lpPoint);
            
            System.Drawing.Size sz = new System.Drawing.Size();
            sz.Height = 100;
            sz.Width = 100;

            var bounds = new Rectangle(lpPoint, sz);
            var image = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(new System.Drawing.Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), System.Drawing.Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }

            image.Save(@"C:\temp\newss.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as issue one, where you want the arrow cursor to be at the center of screenshot, would appear fairly straight forward. If the size of the screenshot is 100x100 then it would appear that when you get the `Point` of the cursor that you would want to move the `X` value -50 and the `Y` value -50. Basically half the width and height of the screenshot rectangle size. This would put the cursor at the center of the screenshot rectangle.

The only thing you may want to look for is if the cursor’s `X` or `Y` positions are less than 50, in which case we would simply set the value to 0. Adding these changes to `lpPoint` should fix this. Something like…

```
lpPoint.X = lpPoint.X >= 50 ? lpPoint.X - 50 : 0;
lpPoint.Y = lpPoint.Y >= 50 ? lpPoint.Y - 50 : 0;
```

For the second issue I can only assume this may have something to do with possibly different resolutions of the monitors. I would think it would still work, as it appears to work in my small tests. However, this is speculation on my part. Can you show a screen shot of both monitors showing what you are describing?

Comment: For issue #2 I know what is causing problem the I just don't know how to solve it.  Here are my display settings


Monitor 1 Screen Resolution = 1366 x 768   
Monitor 1 Scale and Layout = 100% 
Monitor 2 Screen Resolution = 1920 X 1080
Monitor 2 Scale and Layout = 125%


Because monitor #2 has different scale settings it throws off the screen capture.